# Why is my cat lethargic, spaced out, and has air bubbles under her skin?

Tags: cats, health

When I opened the front door this morning my cat was just lying there. She has been lethargic all day. She's usually very playful but today she has been lying around and sleeping. She ate with the other cats but I haven't seen her drink any water. Her eyes are very glossy and she looks so spaced out.

The weirdest thing just happened: When I petted her, her skin popped as though there were air bubbles under the skin. You could feel and hear it popping.

What is wrong with my cat?

Comment: take your cat to a vet now.

Comment: TAKE YOUR CAT TO A VET URGENTLY!!

Answer (score 19):

This is a medical emergency, take your cat to the vet immediately if you have not already done so.

From your description it sounds like your cat has developed subcutaneous emphysema, which most commonly occurs due to trauma to the trachea or lungs. Air can also develop under the skin from severe bacterial growth usually secondary to a wound.

Any time you observe such abnormal mentation (glossy eyes, spaced out), something serious is going on. Nobody online is going to be able to tell you the cause, or how to fix it. The cat needs immediate veterinary attention.